# Duplicity missing backup chains

Tags: backup, duplicity

I backed up my system a while ago and now when i reinstall  Ubuntu 19.10, i tried to restore it from the backup but after a lot of trials i could not get duplicity to work, it always return the error

```
duplicity.dup_collections.CollectionsError: No backup chains found
```

My command is

```
duplicity restore "file:///media/user/2bhd/backup/" /back
```

I checked the path several times by adding, removing slashes but it is still the same so that could not be the reason why.

It turns out that there is no duplicity signature file

```
duplicity-full-signatures.XXXX.diftar.gz
```

in the backup directory so that maybe is the reason duplicity does not work so i wanted to ask if there is any possibility of restoring my files without the signature file.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210835/duplicity-restore-produces-an-error-no-backup-chains-found

Comment: @user535733 i tried that but the main problem, i think, is the missing signature file

Comment: no collections, no backup ;). head over to the duplicity mailing list and provide a list of files on your backend. ..ede/duply.net

Answer (score 1):

if

```
duplicity collection-status "file:///media/user/2bhd/backup/"
```

does not return any valid backup chains, then your backup is corrupted unfortunately.

..ede/duply.net